# A step in the proof of poisson summation formula in stein shakarchi's complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

The step I am confused with is (paraphrasing from pg 118):
If $f \in \mathcal{F}$, since $\frac{1}{e^{2 \pi i z} - 1}$ has simple poles with residue $\frac{1}{2 \pi i}$ at the integers, then $\frac{f(z)}{e^{2 \pi i z} - 1}$ has simple poles at the integers $n$, with residues $\frac{f(n)}{2 \pi i}$.

The relevant definition i that $\mathcal{F}_a$ is the class of all functions $f$ that satisfy the two conditions:

1. The function $f$ is holomorphic in the horizontal strip
   \begin{equation}
   S_a = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |Im(z)| < a
   \end{equation}
2. There exists a constant $A > 0$ such that 
   \begin{equation}
   |f(x + i y)| \leq \frac{A}{1 + x^2}
   \end{equation}
   for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|y| < a$.

We denote by $\mathcal{F}$ the class of all functions that belong to $\mathcal{F}_a$ for some $a$.

I'm confused because if $f$ has a zero at integer $n$, then $\frac{f(z)}{e^{2 \pi i z} - 1}$  would not have a simple pole (and instead be holomorphic in a region around $n$), right?

And it would not affect the argument because we can just take the residue to be zero, and the proof will go the same, right? I'm just worried I'm missing something that forces $\frac{f(z)}{e^{2 \pi i z} - 1}$  to have a simple pole at each of the integers.

Comment: yes, sometimes it is convenient to say a pole of order $1$ with residue $0$ means the function is holomorphic

Comment: To nitpick, $f(z) = z/z$ isn't holomorphic at $z=0$. It has a removable singularity there. The residue at a removable singularity is always $0$.